# Cannot run a comnand. Get this error: `s6-overlay-suexec: fatal: can only run as pid 1`

Tags: docker, heroku

I'm trying to run a command in a heroku docker app, but any command I try I get this strange error:

```
s6-overlay-suexec: fatal: can only run as pid 1
```

This is [the repo](https://github.com/ggsalas/calibre-news) I use for the heroku app, this is the

Dockerfile:

```
FROM linuxserver/calibre

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends -qq\
 curl neovim

COPY . /home

WORKDIR /home

ENV KINDLE_HOME_DIR "/home"
ENV FTP_USER "$FTP_USER"
ENV FTP_PASSWORD "$FTP_PASSWORD"

RUN chmod +x /home/getDailyPublications.sh
```

and the heroku.yml:

```
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile
run:
  web: sh /home/getDailyPublications.sh
```

I'm a newbie in relation to docker, I gess this woild be a very basic question but I cannot find any information about it.

If I deploy the app in heroku, the `sh /home/getDailyPublications.sh` command will be executed.

Instead I get this error (from heroku logs):

```
2022-10-29T15:10:26.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-10-29T15:10:47.998494+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c sh\ /home/getDailyPublications.sh`
2022-10-29T15:10:48.948374+00:00 app[web.1]: s6-overlay-suexec: fatal: can only run as pid 1
2022-10-29T15:10:49.073235+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 100
2022-10-29T15:10:49.138154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: It's _not_ "a very basic" question… as you've no doubt found by now. `s6-overlay` is a linux `init` replacement for containers (used by all the **linuxserver** images I've tried), and it seems to me that heroku is actually not replacing the Dockerfile `CMD` with your shell command (because if it did, it should work!)